# What APIs are used to write output to command prompt?

Tags: api, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

Im using OllyDbg to reverse engineer an executable for my lab assignment. My professor has asked a question asking for the APIs responsible for writing output to the command prompt. The DLLS used were ntdll, kernel32, msvcr100

Answer (score 0):

There are more than a couple of ways to achieve this but the famous two are [WriteConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) and [WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365747).

From MSDN documentation:

**WriteConsole**

> Writes a character string to a console screen buffer beginning at the
>   current cursor location.
>
> ```
> BOOL WINAPI WriteConsole(
>   _In_             HANDLE  hConsoleOutput,
>   _In_       const VOID    *lpBuffer,
>   _In_             DWORD   nNumberOfCharsToWrite,
>   _Out_            LPDWORD lpNumberOfCharsWritten,
>   _Reserved_       LPVOID  lpReserved
> );
> ```

**WriteFile**

> Writes data to the specified file or input/output (I/O) device. This
>   function is designed for both synchronous and asynchronous operation.
>
> ```
> BOOL WINAPI WriteFile(
>   _In_        HANDLE       hFile,
>   _In_        LPCVOID      lpBuffer,
>   _In_        DWORD        nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
>   _Out_opt_   LPDWORD      lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
>   _Inout_opt_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
> );
> ```
>
> ...
>   ...
>   Characters can be written to the screen buffer using WriteFile with a
>   handle to console output. The exact behavior of the function is
>   determined by the console mode. The data is written to the current
>   cursor position. The cursor position is updated after the write
>   operation.